Noncommutative transcendence degree of representation algebras
Let $G$ be a reductive group, for example $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let $V$ denote its defining representation, and let $R$ denote the tensor algebra on the irreducible representations of $G$. It may naively be formed as a quotient of the infinitely generated algebra $R[\rho_i]$ for $\rho_i$ denoting isomorphism classes of irreps of $G$, by the two sided ideal generated by isomorphisms of representations.
Question: has this object been studied? Is there a good notion of "Krull Dimension" for such algebras? If so, is it ever finite for any of the classical groups? Is this algebra finitely presented? Noetherian in the appropriate sense?

What do you mean by irreducible representations of $V$ when $V$ is its defining representation? What is a representation of a representation?

Are you talking about the representation ring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_ring)? This is completely understood for the reductive groups. For $GL_n$ it is isomorphic in a fairly explicit way to the ring of symmetric functions in $n$ variables, where the isomorphism is given by taking the character thought of as a function on diagonal matrices, and in particular it is finitely presented and has Krull dimension $n$. In general it is isomorphic (over $\mathbb{C}$) to $S(\mathfrak{h}^{\ast})^W$ where $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra and $W$ is the Weyl group.

@DaveBenson that's a typo, that $V$ should be $G$.

Yeah Qiaochu, that's precisely what I was asking about. Thanks!
